# Is it possible to add Cocos2d/3d into a project that is already started in xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, integration

I already have a project started and now I have decided it would be easier to do the animations with Cocos2d and want to add it into the project.  Is this possible or do you need to completely start over and do everything in cocos2d.  I do have a NSTimer in it and I know things like that you can't use in cocos2d.  Or is there a way to do animations in good old xcode with out cocos2d with moving images across the screen where the same image continues to come up and rolls across the screen?

Comment: From anecdotal experience, I would start from scratch with Cocos2D.  Experiences may vary..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add cocos2d/3d to a project. Starting a new project would let you start out fresh like @hspain mentioned, and the initialization procedure will be setup for you, since cocos2d will be controlling the app.

If you are using revision and rewriting your code from scratch to use cocos2d is not an option. I would create a static library target and add the cocos2d sources to the target.  Then link the new target library to your app target. If you are doing it this way you need to decide if cocos2d controls the app or is just used and based on that the initialization procedure will be different like @LearnCocos2D mentioned in the comment.

> Or is there a way to do animations in good old xcode with out cocos2d with moving images across the screen where the same image continues to come up and rolls across the screen?

I haven't tried using animations other than with cocos2d, but you could take a look at the Core Animation API.

Comment: you're forgetting about the whole initialization procedure, which is different depending on whether cocos2d controls the app or is merely added to it.

Comment: you're right. I was more focused on adding cocos2d to the project, but will update the answer.